# Deleting an object from a dynamically allocated array of objects in a class

Tags: c++

I have a very simple problem, but due to my inexperience in C++ i can't seem to solve it. I have a class PlayList which has a dynamically allocated array as a private data member. I have never used dynamic arrays and I'm confused on how to add a specific object and delete a specific object. I am passing by a Song object by reference and need to delete it. How would I do that? My current code is below(Song is a separate class which I'm not including)

```
#ifndef PROJ5_PLAYLIST_H_INCLUDED
#define PROJ5_PLAYLIST_H_INCLUDED
#include "song.h"
#include <iostream>

class PlayList{

private:
    Song* playList_arr;
    int size_of_playlist;
    int numberOfSongs;
public:

    PlayList();
    ~PlayList();
    void AddSong(const Song& s);
    bool DeleteSong(const Song& s);
    void ShowAll() const;
    void play(int num=1);
    void ShowStatus()const;

};

#endif // PROJ5_PLAYLIST_H_INCLUDED
```

.cpp file

```
  #include <iostream>
#include "proj5_playlist.h"


PlayList::PlayList()
{
    size_of_playlist = 2;
    numberOfSongs = 0;
    playList_arr = new Song[size_of_playlist];
}

PlayList::~PlayList()
{
    delete [] playList_arr;
}

void PlayList::AddSong(const Song& s)
{
    if(numberOfSongs==size_of_playlist){
        Song* arr=new Song[size_of_playlist+1];
        arr[size_of_playlist]=s;
        for(int i=0;i<size_of_playlist;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=playList_arr[i];
        }
        playList_arr=arr;
        delete arr;
        arr = NULL;
    }
    else{
        numberOfSongs++;
        playList_arr[numberOfSongs-1] = s;
    }

}


void PlayList::DeleteSong(const Song& s)
{


}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector<Song>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard library object (for instance vector or linkedlist).
If you really want to use your dynamic array, try this:

```
void PlayList::DeleteSong(const Song& s)
{
  // First search specified song
  int index;
  for (index = 0; index < numberOfSongs; index++)
  {
    if (playList_arr[index] == s) // You should implement operator==
      break;
  }

  // Maybe not found
  if (index == numberOfSongs)
  {
    ...
    return;
  }

  // Remove song fron array
  while (index < (numberOfSongs-1))
  {
    playList_arr[index] = playList_arr[index+1];
    index++;
  }

  // We got one less song
  numberOfSongs--;

} // DeleteSong
```